# Is this subgroup normal?

Tags: group-theory

Let $H,K$ be subgroups of $G$. Let $N = \langle h^{-1}k^{-1}hk : h \in H, k \in K \rangle$. Is $N$ normal in $\langle H,K \rangle$?

Comment: what is $⟨H,K⟩$? direct product?

Comment: @Idonknow No it's the subgroup generated by $H$ and $K$.

Comment: This looks to be a form of commutator subgroup.

Comment: No, $N = [H,K]$ is the commutator subgroup of $H$ and $K$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is. Observe the following:

1: If $g\in H, h\in H,k\in K$, then $ghkh^{-1}k^{-1}g^{-1}=(gh)k(gh)^{-1}k^{-1}kgk^{-1}g^{-1} \in N$, since $kgk^{-1}g^{-1} = (gkg^{-1}k^{-1})^{-1} \in N$.

2:If $g \in K, h\in H,k\in K$, then $ghkh^{-1}k^{-1}g^{-1}= ghg^{-1}h^{-1}h(gk)h^{-1}(gk)^{-1}\in N$, since $ghg^{-1}h^{-1} = (hgh^{-1}g^{-1})^{-1} \in N$.

Using the above two observation, one can show that if $l \in \langle H,K \rangle, h\in N$, then $lhl^{-1} \in N$.